# How to go through a set of numbers with a single variable in a while-if statement

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

How would I have java run through these set of numbers:

> 7, -15, 85, 100, 29, 16, 5, 12, 90, 150, -4, 17, 30, 55, 2

in my while-if statement? I want these numbers to be in place of the variable, "number".

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 15) {
  if (number > 25)
  {
    count++;
    total++;
    addTotal = (addTotal + number);
  }
  else
    count++
```

I'm ultimately trying to figure out the average of all numbers greater than 25.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in an array:

```
int[] numbers = {7, -15, 85, 100, 29, 16, 5, 12, 90, 150, -4, 17, 30, 55, 2};
```

Then iterate with a for loop (... unless "using while" is a requirement ...)

```
numberOfNumbersGreater25 = 0;
sum = 0;
for (int number:numbers) {
 if (number > 25) {
   sum += number;
   numberOfNumbersGreater25++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Integer> numebrs = Arrays.asList(7, -15, 85, 100, 29, 16, 5, 12, 90, 150, -4, 17, 30, 55, 2);
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int numberOfNumbersGreater25 = 0;
    while(count < numebrs.size()) {
        int number = numebrs.get(count);
        if(number > 25) {
            total += number;
            numberOfNumbersGreater25++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if(numberOfNumbersGreater25 > 0) {
        System.out.println("Average: " + (total / (float)numberOfNumbersGreater25));            
    } else {
        System.out.println("No number grater than 25 in the list");
    }
```

Output:

Average: 77.0